# Return value if array item is not listed in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

Here is the scenario.
I have an array of items:

```
const memberArray = ["-Lz8YxHbn5iOCxaGUBZt", "-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn", "-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO", -Lz8YxHfasdfsdfGUBZt];
```

Then I have an array of objects.

```
const memberObjects = [
{name: 'john', uid: '-Lz8YxHbn5iOCxaGUBZt'},
{name: 'steve', uid: '-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn'},
{name: 'marcus', uid: '-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO'}
]
```

I need to return the value if an item in memberArray is not listed in memberObjects.
In the above example: `-Lz8YxHfasdfsdfGUBZt` is not listed in memberObjects so it should return.

Any idea how I could accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: everything lol let me add it @Adassko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it:

```js
const memberArray = ["-Lz8YxHbn5iOCxaGUBZt", "-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn", "-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO", "-Lz8YxHfasdfsdfGUBZt"];
const memberObjects = [
    {name: 'john', uid: '-Lz8YxHbn5iOCxaGUBZt'},
    {name: 'steve', uid: '-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn'},
    {name: 'marcus', uid: '-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO'}
];
console.log(memberArray.some(o => !memberObjects.some(({uid}) => uid == o)));
```

Comment: @hev1 yes, sorry, first thought was to extract the values, but it's actually not necessary

Comment: Good stuff.  I was so close! I did filter and then was going to includes but got stuck on the includes.  @Berto99

Comment: @FabricioG yes well, i was actually mapping values on the first, so Higer order functions can be useful, but sometimes you don't know which is better to use

Comment: @FabricioG this solution has complexity of `n^2` and may be really slow. if you have many elements, you may need to extract values you're comparing to, to a Set, and use `has` function on it instead of `some`

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip, I'm a look into that @Adassko